# loading screen without progress dialog android

Tags: android, user-interface, progress-bar

I am using async task and my loading screen is as shown in image
[image]

But i want to show only that blue progress line not the dialog. what should i do?

here is my code

```
      @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS: //we set this to 0
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar_states));
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait while checking new database");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                
              mProgressDialog.show();
                
              
                return mProgressDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Or how can i show only that percentage 53% or 53/100 in above image without dialog?

I just solve how to show the percentage but no 'progress' on progress line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use to display the seekbar in dialog and its progress.Below code R.layout.pg contains one seekbar.Add more code whatever you want.
In Oncreate:

Seekbar seek;

```
{
         d = new Dialog(this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        LayoutInflater inflter=getLayoutInflater();
        View v=inflter.inflate(R.layout.pg, null);
        seek=(SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        d.setContentView(v);

        d.show();
        new Myasync().execute();

    }
    Dialog d ;
class Myasync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    boolean isTrue=true;
    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        while(isTrue)
        {

            publishProgress(i++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(i>100)
            {
                isTrue=false;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
    {
        d.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        seek.setProgress(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```